# Invalid signature connect to Coinbase

Tags: c++, authentication, signature, quickfix, coinbase-api

I try connect to coinbase, but I have failed:
These are the three functions, which I use for auth
I have added a false bool value here for insertLineBreaks as the default true value was breaking the signature. There shouldn't be any reason to add line breaks to the Base64 decoding.

```
 void toAdmin(FIX::Message& msg, const FIX::SessionID& session)
  {
      std::string sendingTime = msg.getHeader().getField(52);
      std::string msgType = msg.getHeader().getField(35);
      std::string msgSeqNum = msg.getHeader().getField(34);
      std::string senderCompId = msg.getHeader().getField(49);
      std::string targetCompId = msg.getHeader().getField(56);
      std::string password = "myPassword";


      std::string rawDara = sendingTime + '\x01' + msgType + '\x01' + msgSeqNum + '\x01' + senderCompId + '\x01' + targetCompId + '\x01' + password + '\x01';
      std::cout << rawDara << std::endl;

      std::string secret = "mySecret";
      std::vector<BYTE> secret_decode64_byte = Base64_decode(secret);
      std::string secret_decode64_byte_str(secret_decode64_byte.begin(), secret_decode64_byte.end());

      std::string rawDara_sha256 = sign(secret_decode64_byte_str, rawDara);

      msg.setField(98,"0");
      msg.setField(108, "30");
      msg.setField(554, "MyAPIPassphrase");
      msg.setField(96, rawDara_sha256);
      msg.setField(8013, "Y");
      msg.setField(9406, "Y");
  }
```

---

```
std::vector<BYTE> Application::Base64_decode(std::string encoded_string)
{
const BYTE from_base64[256] = { 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
                                    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
                                    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  62, 255,  62, 255,  63,
                                     52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
                                    255,   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,
                                     15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25, 255, 255, 255, 255,  63,
                                    255,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,
                                     41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255 };
    // Make sure string length is a multiple of 4
    while ((encoded_string.size() % 4) != 0)
        encoded_string.push_back('=');

    size_t encoded_size = encoded_string.size();
    std::vector<BYTE> ret;
    ret.reserve(3 * encoded_size / 4);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < encoded_size; i += 4)
    {
        // Get values for each group of four base 64 characters
        BYTE b4[4];
        b4[0] = (encoded_string[i + 0] <= 'z') ? from_base64[encoded_string[i + 0]] : 0xff;
        b4[1] = (encoded_string[i + 1] <= 'z') ? from_base64[encoded_string[i + 1]] : 0xff;
        b4[2] = (encoded_string[i + 2] <= 'z') ? from_base64[encoded_string[i + 2]] : 0xff;
        b4[3] = (encoded_string[i + 3] <= 'z') ? from_base64[encoded_string[i + 3]] : 0xff;

        // Transform into a group of three bytes
        BYTE b3[3];
        b3[0] = ((b4[0] & 0x3f) << 2) + ((b4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        b3[1] = ((b4[1] & 0x0f) << 4) + ((b4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
        b3[2] = ((b4[2] & 0x03) << 6) + ((b4[3] & 0x3f) >> 0);

        // Add the byte to the return value if it isn't part of an '=' character (indicated by 0xff)
        if (b4[1] != 0xff) ret.push_back(b3[0]);
        if (b4[2] != 0xff) ret.push_back(b3[1]);
        if (b4[3] != 0xff) ret.push_back(b3[2]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

---

```
std::string Application::sign(std::string key, std::string plain)
{
    std::string mac, encoded;
    try
    {
        HMAC< SHA256 > hmac((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());

        StringSource(plain, true,
            new HashFilter(hmac,
                new StringSink(mac)
            ) // HashFilter      
        ); // StringSource
    }
    catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    encoded.clear();
    // Added false bool value here for insertLineBreaks 
    StringSource(mac, true,
        new Base64Encoder(
            new StringSink(encoded), false
        ) 
    );
    std::cout << "encode: " << encoded << std::endl;
    return encoded;
}
```

I can't auth to coinbase, invalid signature. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing 1. how your output FIX message (that you send) looks like and 2. how you are expected to sign the message. Can you add a link to the Coinbase API that describes this?

Comment: https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/?php#logon-a

Comment: From the spec: "There is no trailing separator". You have one after password. On another note: it's called `RawData`. :)

Comment: Ok,I try this: 
`std::string rawDara = sendingTime + '\x01' + msgType + '\x01' + msgSeqNum + '\x01' + senderCompId + '\x01' + targetCompId + '\x01' + password`
but it's not work too

Comment: Your password is first `myPassword` then (further below) it is `MyAPIPassphrase`. Which one is correct?

Comment: Yes, it's the same = MyAPIPassphrase

Comment: You sure get invalid signature? Not checksum? Can you paste the error FIX message?

Comment: 8=FIX.4.29=12835=334=149=Coinbase52=20210608-16:52:04.56456=MYAPIKEY45=158=invalid signature371=96372=A373=510=087

Comment: I think what you want for your prehash String is not e.g. `getField(56)` (which returns `56=Coinbase`) but `getField(56).getValue()` or even better `getString(56)` which only returns the field value.

Comment: 1. I get tag 56 from code : `std::string targetCompId = msg.getHeader().getField(56);` and I see this value in Debug, it is true
2. `getField(56).getValue()` or `getString(56)` not exist in quickfix

Comment: OK, probably quickfix is different from QuickFIX/J there. So probably your problem lies in the other code, but I am afraid I cannot help you further there.